# Unable to use Unity UI elements on my android

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I just created a very simple 3D game, and I used Unity UI for the first time.
Inside the game editor I can click the buttons and move the sliders.
I build the game for my android,and I can see all UI elements on my device but however, for some reason, I just can't use them.

Can you please help me and explain what am I doing wrong? Is it a bug?

Comment: I just tried in my Android 4.4 phone with a simple button and it works well. What version of Unity and Android are you using ?

Comment: Unity 4.6, also Android 4.4.

Comment: Just like me. Do you have a sample project you can upload to see why it fails ?

Comment: Check if you have TouchInputModule enabled on the EventSystem gameobject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

The Canvas element comes with "EventSystem" object. All I had to do is to check the CheckBox called "Allow Activation on Mobile device"...[image: See yellow rect]